# How to use PyTorch multiprocessing?

Tags: python, computer-vision, multiprocessing, pytorch

I'm trying to use python's multiprocessing `Pool` method in `pytorch` to process a image. Here's the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom

def get_pred(args):

  img = args[0]
  scale = args[1]
  scales = args[2]
  img_scale = zoom(img.numpy(),
                     (1., 1., scale, scale),
                     order=1,
                     prefilter=False,
                     mode='nearest')

  # feed input data
  input_img = Variable(torch.from_numpy(img_scale),
                     volatile=True).cuda()
  return input_img

scales = [1,2,3,4,5]
scale_list = []
for scale in scales: 
    scale_list.append([img,scale,scales])
multi_pool = Pool(processes=5)
predictions = multi_pool.map(get_pred,scale_list)
multi_pool.close() 
multi_pool.join()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
`RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

`
In this line:

```
predictions = multi_pool.map(get_pred,scale_list)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As stated in [pytorch documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/multiprocessing.html) the best practice to handle multiprocessing is to use `torch.multiprocessing` instead of `multiprocessing`.

Be aware that sharing CUDA tensors between processes is supported only in Python 3, either with `spawn` or `forkserver` as start method.

Without touching your code, a workaround for the error you got is replacing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
```

with:

```
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process, set_start_method
try:
     set_start_method('spawn')
except RuntimeError:
    pass
```

Comment: Sometimes even `torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)`

Comment: Make sure to have your main loop delimited by `if __name__ == '__main__':` in this case as global statements will be executed upon a spawn

Comment: This solved one issue but introduced another, `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you read the docs for the multiprocessing module, especially [this section](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). You will have to change the way subprocesses are created by calling `set_start_method`. Taken from those quoted docs:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```