# Using SentenceTransformers stucks on Batches: 0%|

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, huggingface-transformers, embedding, sentence-transformers

I'm using SentenceTransformers python pkg in a multi-process program and I think I have some race condition issue.

The code looks like that:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')
emb1 = model.encode(user_input)

class A:

    def foo(text):
        emb2 = model.encode(text)
        print("calculated emb2!")
        return util.cos_sim(emb1, emb2)
```

Calculating emb1 succeeded, but when I call foo(), the call to encode stucks on:
Batches: 0%|

Any idea how to overcome this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use torch.multiprocessing instead of Python's native multiprocessing: PyTorch has its own multiprocessing module that's a drop-in replacement for Python's multiprocessing. It supports the same operations but extends it to move all tensors sent through a multiprocessing.Queue into shared memory, and only sends a handle to another process.

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

class A:
    def __init__(self, model_name='all-mpnet-base-v2'):
        self.model = SentenceTransformer(model_name)

    def worker(self, text, queue):
        emb2 = self.model.encode(text)
        print("calculated emb2! :)")
        queue.put(util.cos_sim(emb1, emb2))

    def foo(self, text):
        mp.set_start_method('spawn')  # 'spawn' or 'forkserver' start method
        queue = mp.SimpleQueue()
        p = mp.Process(target=self.worker, args=(text, queue))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        return queue.get()

# Usage:
a = A()
emb1 = a.model.encode(user_input)
result = a.foo(text)
```

- [How to use PyTorch multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822463/how-to-use-pytorch-multiprocessing)
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html