# Multiprocessing not allowed in pytorch training

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, multiprocessing, daemon

I tried setting up multiple sub-processes, and using `PyTorch` to train a *separate model* on a *separate dataset* **within each sub-process**. Here is my code: (no `cuda`/GPU involved yet)

```
##################################################################################
# this part of code has nothing to do with the error, we include it for the completeness
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

class CADataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  '''
  Prepare the Boston dataset for regression
  '''
  def __init__(self, X, y, scale_data=True):
    if not torch.is_tensor(X) and not torch.is_tensor(y):
      # Apply scaling if necessary
      if scale_data:
          X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
      self.X = torch.from_numpy(X)
      self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)

  def __len__(self):
      return len(self.X)

  def __getitem__(self, i):
      return self.X[i], self.y[i]

class MLP(nn.Module):
  '''
    Multilayer Perceptron for regression.
  '''
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.layers = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Linear(8, 32),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(32, 16),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(16, 1)
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    '''
      Forward pass
    '''
    return self.layers(x)

def mlp_demo(branchID: int):
  housing = fetch_california_housing() # in this toy example data from all branches are the same, while in my real application they are not.
  print('in branch {}'.format(branchID))
  print(housing.data.shape)
  print(housing.target.shape)

  # Prepare CA dataset
  dataset = CADataset(housing.data, housing.target)
  trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

  # Initialize the MLP
  mlp = MLP()

  # Define the loss function and optimizer
  loss_function = nn.L1Loss()
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mlp.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

  # Run the training loop
  for epoch in range(0, 5): # 5 epochs at maximum

    # Print epoch
    print(f'Starting epoch {epoch+1}')

    # Set current loss value
    current_loss = 0.0

    # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
      # Get and prepare inputs
      inputs, targets = data
      inputs, targets = inputs.float(), targets.float()
      targets = targets.reshape((targets.shape[0], 1))
      # Zero the gradients
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      # Perform forward pass
      outputs = mlp(inputs)
      # Compute loss
      loss = loss_function(outputs, targets)
      # Perform backward pass
      loss.backward()
      # Perform optimization
      optimizer.step()
      # Print statistics
      current_loss += loss.item()
      if i % 20 == 0:
          print('Loss after mini-batch %5d: %.3f' %
                (i + 1, current_loss / 500))
          current_loss = 0.0
  # Process is complete.
  print('Training process has finished.')

##################################################################################
# above code has nothing to do with the error, we include it for the completeness

from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Set fixed random number seed
  torch.manual_seed(42)
  try:
    set_start_method('spawn')
  except RuntimeError:
    pass

  with Pool() as pool:
      pool.map(mlp_demo, range(3))
```

I learnt to import the `set_start_method` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822463/how-to-use-pytorch-multiprocessing), but I still got the following error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/home/wangyu/code/test_cuda/demo.py", line 72, in mlp_demo
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 441, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 388, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1042, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 118, in start
    assert not _current_process._config.get('daemon'), \
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wangyu/code/test_cuda/demo.py", line 110, in <module>
    pool.map(mlp_demo, range(3))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

In my real application, I have several datasets, and their trainings are independent. I know I could run multiple instances of `python3 my_script.py --dataset=<my_ds>`, but since their pre-processings are correlated and the results of the trainings are to be aggregated, I really want it could be done within one python script (and one python instance).

Is there any way taht I can fix the `demon` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace:

```
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method
```

With:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
```

To avoid to start your (pool) processes as daemon and allow them to create sub-processes.